# Does the Sensor Tower sense cloaked units?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I see my opponent has a Sensor Tower up, is it still safe to attack with Dark Templar or cloaked Banshees?  Will he see them coming on the minimap?

What about burrowed Roaches?  Will the Sensor Tower still sense those even if it can't sense cloaked units?

I understand that the Sensor Tower is not a detector and will not give vision of the units.  I am inquiring as to whether it will alert the player to the PRESENCE of them, even if you still can't target them without an additional source of detection.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The radar ability of the sensor tower will not detect cloaked or burrowed units, regardless of whether they are within the fog of war.

Picture:[image]

Editor View:[image]

Comment: I thought they did, but that was a painful mistake...

Comment: Wow... then what is the point of sensor towers? They don't seem that useful to me.

Comment: They give you a heads up regarding air drops and army movements.

Answer (score 10):

Sensor towers are not detectors so no they will not see them.  For the purposes of detection burrow is identical to cloak.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it is correct. [This page](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Sensor_tower/Development#cite_note-CydraSensor-6) quotes a Blizzard Battle.net thread: "Do cloaked and burrowed units appear as blips within the radar's range?" "No. Cloaked and burrowed units don't appear." It was a detector at various times during beta but the ability was removed.